# Pass pointer of child type to dummy argument that takes a pointer of parent class

Tags: fortran

When I attempt to pass a pointer of an extended type to a routine that takes a pointer to the class of the parent type I get a type-mismatch error. However, in the second case where the dummy argument is not a pointer it compiles fine.

The child_type is a class of parent_type and they both have the pointer attribute, so everything seems to match, and it works when the dummy argument isn't a pointer.

So, why does it fail if the dummy argument is a pointer?

```
module wrong_type_test
  implicit none

  type parent_type
     integer :: a
  end type parent_type

  type, extends(parent_type) :: child_type
     integer :: b
  end type child_type

contains

  subroutine ptr_test(parent_ptr)
    class(parent_type), pointer, intent(inout) :: parent_ptr
    print *, "test"
  end subroutine ptr_test

  subroutine non_ptr_test(parent)
    class(parent_type), intent(inout) :: parent
    print *, "test"
  end subroutine non_ptr_test

end module wrong_type_test

program test
  use wrong_type_test
  implicit none

  class(child_type), pointer :: child_ptr

  call non_ptr_test(child_ptr) !this works
  call ptr_test(child_ptr) !this doesn't work
end program test
```

ifort error:

```
select_type_pointer_test.f90(33): error #6633: The type of the actual argument differs from the type of the dummy argument.   [CHILD_PTR]
  call ptr_test(child_ptr)
```

gfortran error:

```
Error: Actual argument to 'parent_ptr' at (1) must have the same declared type
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the pointer dummy argument case, the procedure can reassociate the pointer to an object that is of a different extension type to the actual argument.  This is not a sensible thing to do, so the language prohibits it.

In general, dummy arguments should only be pointers when you want to do something related to the pointer association status of the argument.

Comment: How can you associate the pointer to something that isn't an extension of the parent type? If the pointer is of the child type then doesn't anything it points to also have to be an extension of the parent type too?

Comment: Inside the procedure, the declared type of the pointer is the parent type.  Inside the procedure the pointer can then be pointed to another type that is a *sibling* (or an extension of a sibling) of your child type - common parent, different extensions.  Then when the procedure ends and execution is back in the calling scope, chaos ensues.